# Ideal way of accessing database wrapper inside another class

Tags: php, database, oop, wrapper

I have a class named DB which is a PDO database wrapper. It has functions for selecting, updating, inserting and deleting records for a table.

```
class db {

    public $conn; //PDO

    public function __construct()
    {...
    }

    public function select($table, $fields = '*' , $where = '1=1', $params = array()) { 
        ....
    }
}
```

I am accessing the functions of this class inside another class by this method:

```
class MyAPI extends API
{
public $db;
public function __construct($request) {

    parent::__construct($request);
    $this->db = new db();   

}
public function dosomething()
{
    $this->db->select(...);
}
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it? I mean making an object of the db class in the main class and accessing it. Can this be done in a better way in terms on object oriented programming?

Comment: Start by reading about [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: @KKanishkDudeja: Yes there is nothing wrong with that but may you should have `private $db;`

Comment: @anubhava: I am building a rest api in php based on the corey maynard link u sent me. i have made some changes in the code. 

i have to implement the api as a test for a job interview. Would you be able to help me review the code since i am new to restful api's and just point out any issues with the code.

Thanks a lot anyway for your reply.

Comment: @FDL: Can u please explain how dependency injection will be better off in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use.

```
public static function getInstance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new DB();
        echo "Connected";
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}
```

and

```
$this->db = DB::getInstance();
```

So that you won't instantiate the DB class more than one time. This will increase the efficacy of your code. And reduce load on your database since you only connect to it only once.